# how can i update data on pymongo well?

Tags: pymongo

i inserted `data` into mongodb to use pymongo like this.

```
data = {
       'page_url': product_link,
       'static': {
           'created_at': datetime.datetime.now(),
           'created_at_gmt': datetime.datetime.now(),       
                        },
       'created_at': datetime.datetime.now(),
       'created_at_gmt': datetime.datetime.now(),
       'updated_at': datetime.datetime.now(),
       'updated_at_gmt': datetime.datetime.now()

db.product.insert_one(data)
```

then when i updated `data`, i removed `created_at` and  `created_at_gmt`.

```
data = {
       'page_url': product_link,
       'static': {
                        },
       'updated_at': datetime.datetime.now(),
       'updated_at_gmt': datetime.datetime.now()

db.product.update_one({'page_url': product_link}, {"$set": data}, upsert=True)
```

but after i updated it, when i checked db data on compass, there was no `created_at` and `created_at_gmt` in `static`. on in `static`. there was `created_at` and `created_at_gmt` on same depth with static.

i don't know why it heppend...

can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

You should only update the keys you want to in the `$set` stage.

```py
current_datetime = datetime.datetime.now()

db.product.update_one({
  'page_url': product_link
}, {
  "$set": {
    'updated_at': current_datetime ,
    'updated_at_gmt': current_datetime 
  }
}, upsert=True)
```

Like the above example, you should only reference the keys you want to update.

Have a look at `$unset` update command if you want to remove a key from a MongoDB Document.

Also, store the `datetime` value in a variable, so that it is uniform.